# MySQL Cluster 7.3.2 - Query Cache and Indexing

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-error-1064

I'm having some issues with Query cache and Indexing using MySQL Cluster.
How do i set "query_cache_type=1"? I understand that this is different from normal MySQL where i could simply modify the my.ini file in ProgramData -> MySQL5.6.

Also, whats the correct way of indexing here. I.e. Normally its something like create index user on usertb (userid);

Please assist. Thanks!